# Liquid includes Share Page

Tags: html, template, jekyll, liquid

This week I published a project that aims to enable sharing Jekyll built pages on various social media platforms, without unnecessarily degrading client privacy; ie. it does **not** call-out to those third-party sites unless a client actively clicks a share link.

Currently supported sites are:

- Facebook
- Linked-In
- Reddit
- Twitter

---

### Questions

- Are there any features for modification that need to be added?
- Got suggestions for making Liquid code easier to extend?
- Is a *must have* missing from the current listing of social media sites?

---

### Requirements

The source code and setup instructions are intended for those utilizing [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com) built sites on GitHub Pages. The Jekyll site has [documentation](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/github-pages/) regarding GitHub Pages, and GitHub has further [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/creating-a-github-pages-site-with-jekyll) regarding Jekyll.

---

### Setup

The [*`ReadMe`*](https://github.com/liquid-utilities/includes-share-page/blob/main/.github/README.md) file contains more detailed instructions for setup, but the TLDR is as follows.

- Change current working directory to a repository utilizing Jekyll to build static web pages...

```
cd ~/git/hub/<name>/<repo>
```

- Check-out the `gh-pages` branch and make directory path for including modules...

```
git checkout gh-pages

mkdir -p _includes/modules
```

- Add this project as a Git Submodule

```
git submodule add -b 'main'\
  --branch 'includes-share-page'\
  'https://github.com/liquid-utilities/includes-share-page.git'\
  '_includes/modules/includes-share-page'
```

> **Notice**, for GitHub Pages one must use the `https` URL for Git Submodules

- Add an `include` statement to your site's layout, eg...

[**`_layouts/post.html`**](https://github.com/liquid-utilities/includes-share-page/blob/gh-pages/_layouts/post.html)

```
---
layout: default
license: MIT
source: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jekyll/minima/v2.0.0/_layouts/post.html
---
<article class="post" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">

  <header class="post-header">
    <h1 class="post-title" itemprop="name headline">{{ page.title | escape }}</h1>
    <p class="post-meta"><time datetime="{{ page.date | date_to_xmlschema }}" itemprop="datePublished">{{ page.date | date: "%b %-d, %Y" }}</time>{% if page.author %} • <span itemprop="author" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person"><span itemprop="name">{{ page.author }}</span></span>{% endif %}</p>
  </header>

  <div class="post-content" itemprop="articleBody">
    {{ content }}
  </div>

  {%- unless page.share == false -%}
    {% include modules/includes-share-page/share-page.html %}
  {%- endunless -%}

  {% if site.disqus.shortname %}
    {% include disqus_comments.html %}
  {% endif %}
</article>
```

- Commit added Git Submodule and theme modifications...

```
git add _layouts/post.html


git commit -F- <<'EOF'
:heavy_plus_sign: Adds `liquid-utilities/includes-share-page#1` submodule



**Adds**


- `.gitmodules`, tracks submodules AKA Git within Git _fanciness_

- `_modules_/includes-share-page`, Builds list of links for sharing on social media sites

- `_layouts/post.html`, modified default layout from `jekyll/minima` theme
EOF
```

---

### Usage

Configure site wide defaults...

[**`_config.yml` (snip)**](https://github.com/liquid-utilities/includes-share-page/blob/gh-pages/_config.yml)

```
share:
  disable_linkedin: true
  figcaption: Share this elsewhere via...
```

- Use standard FrontMatter configurations for the selected layout, modifying any site level defaults on a per-page basis...

[**`_posts/2020-07-19-frontmatter-share.md` (FrontMatter)**](https://github.com/liquid-utilities/includes-share-page/blob/gh-pages/_posts/2020-07-19-frontmatter-share.md)

```
---
layout: post
title: Example Post
description: 'Tests list generated by `includes-share-page/share-page.html` project'
categories: programming webdev
date: 2020-07-19 15:23:03 -0700
share:
  disable_linkedin: true
  text: Customized text for when someone shares a link to this post
---
```

A [*live* example](https://liquid-utilities.github.io/includes-share-page/2020/07/19/frontmatter-share.html) of output above is hosted thanks to GitHub Pages, the resulting HTML for above configurations is similar to...

**`includes-share-page/2020/07/19/frontmatter-share.html` (snip)**

```
<figure class="social-share__container">
  <figcaption>Share this elsewhere via...</figcaption>
  <ul class="social-share__list">

    <li class="social-share__item">
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fauthor.github.io%2Frepo-name%2Fprogramming%2Fwebdev%2F2020%2F07%2F06%2Fexample-post.html"
         class="social-share__link facebook-share fa fa-facebook"
         data-name="Facebook">
        Facebook
      </a>
    </li>

    <li class="social-share__item">
      <a href="https://reddit.com/submit?url=https%3A%2F%2Fauthor.github.io%2Frepo-name%2Fprogramming%2Fwebdev%2F2020%2F07%2F06%2Fexample-post.html&title=Example%20Post"
         class="social-share__link reddit-share fa fa-reddit"
         data-name="Reddit">
        Reddit
      </a>
    </li>

    <li class="social-share__item">
      <a href="https://www.twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=https%3A%2F%2Fauthor.github.io%2Frepo-name%2Fprogramming%2Fwebdev%2F2020%2F07%2F06%2Fexample-post.html&hashtags=programming,webdev&text=Customized%20text%20for%20when%20someone%20shares%20a%20link%20to%20this%20post"
         class="social-share__link twitter-share fa fa-twitter"
         data-name="Twitter">
        Twitter
      </a>
    </li>

  </ul>
</figure>
```

- Commit changes and push to GitHub...

```
git add _posts/2020-07-19-frontmatter-share-page.md

git commit -m ':memo: Adds post FrontMatter HCard'

git push origin gh-pages
```

---

### Source Code

[**`share-page.html`**](https://github.com/liquid-utilities/includes-share-page/blob/main/share-page.html)

```
{% capture workspace__share_page %}
{% comment %}
---
version: 0.0.1
license: AGPL-3.0
author: S0AndS0
---
{% endcomment %}


{% assign share__escaped__page_url = page.url | absolute_url | url_param_escape %}
{% assign share__escaped__page_title = page.title | url_param_escape %}
{% assign share__element_class_block = page.share.element_class_block | default: 'social-share' %}
{% assign share__text = page.share.text | default: page.description | default: page.excerpt | default: nil %}


{% assign share__figcaption = page.share.figcaption %}
{% unless share__figcaption == false or share__figcaption %}
  {% assign share__figcaption = site.share.figcaption %}
{% endunless %}


{% assign share__disable_text = page.share.disable_text | default: site.share.disable_text | default: false %}
{% assign share__disable_facebook = page.share.disable_facebook | default: site.share.disable_facebook %}
{% assign share__disable_linkedin = page.share.disable_linkedin | default: site.share.disable_linkedin %}
{% assign share__disable_reddit = page.share.disable_reddit | default: site.share.disable_reddit %}
{% assign share__disable_twitter = page.share.disable_twitter | default: site.share.disable_twitter %}


{% assign share__tags = page.tags %}

{% unless share__tags == false or share__tags %}
  {% assign share__tags = page.categories %}
{% endunless %}

{% unless share__tags == false or share__tags %}
  {% assign share__tags = page.category | split: ' ' %}
{% endunless %}

{% if share__tags %}
  {% assign share__escaped__hash_tags = nil %}
  {% for tag in share__tags %}
    {% if share__escaped__hash_tags %}
      {% capture share__escaped__hash_tags %}{{ share__escaped__hash_tags }},{{ tag | url_param_escape }}{% endcapture %}
    {% else %}
      {% capture share__escaped__hash_tags %}{{ tag | url_param_escape }}{% endcapture %}
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}


<figure class="{{ share__element_class_block }}__container">
  {% unless share__figcaption == false %}
    {% if figcaption %}
      <figcaption>{{ share__figcaption }}</figcaption>
    {% else %}
      <figcaption>Share via:</figcaption>
    {% endif %}
  {% endunless %}

  <ul class="{{ share__element_class_block }}__list">
    {% comment %}
      Parameters `u`
    {% endcomment %}
    {% unless share__disable_facebook %}
      <li class="{{ share__element_class_block }}__item">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u={{ share__escaped__page_url }}"
           class="{{ share__element_class_block }}__link facebook-share fa fa-facebook"
           data-name="Facebook">
          {% unless share__disable_text %}Facebook{% endunless %}
        </a>
      </li>
    {% endunless %}

    {% comment %}
      Parameters `url`
    {% endcomment %}
    {% unless share__disable_linkedin %}
      <li class="{{ share__element_class_block }}__item">
        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite?url={{ share__escaped__page_url }}"
           class="{{ share__element_class_block }}__link linkedin-share fa fa-linkedin"
           data-name="LinkedIn">
          {% unless share__disable_text %}LinkedIn{% endunless %}
        </a>
      </li>
    {% endunless %}

    {% comment %}
      Parameters `url` `title`
    {% endcomment %}
    {% unless share__disable_reddit %}
      <li class="{{ share__element_class_block }}__item">
        <a href="https://reddit.com/submit?url={{ share__escaped__page_url }}&title={{ share__escaped__page_title }}"
           class="{{ share__element_class_block }}__link reddit-share fa fa-reddit"
           data-name="Reddit">
          {% unless share__disable_text %}Reddit{% endunless %}
        </a>
      </li>
    {% endunless %}

    {% comment %}
      Parameters `url` `text` `via` `hashtags`
      Note `via` == User ID, which is not applicable here
    {% endcomment %}
    {% unless share__disable_twitter %}
      {% if share__text %}
        {% assign twitter_text = share__text | truncate: 140 | url_encode %}
      {% endif %}
      {% assign twitter_query_string = 'url=' | append: share__escaped__page_url %}

      {% if share__escaped__hash_tags %}
        {% assign twitter_query_string = twitter_query_string | append: '&hashtags=' | append: share__escaped__hash_tags %}
      {% endif %}

      {% if twitter_text %}
        {% assign twitter_query_string = twitter_query_string | append: '&text=' | append: twitter_text %}
      {% endif %}

      <li class="{{ share__element_class_block }}__item">
        <a href="https://www.twitter.com/intent/tweet?{{ twitter_query_string }}"
           class="{{ share__element_class_block }}__link twitter-share fa fa-twitter"
           data-name="Twitter">
          {% unless share__disable_text %}Twitter{% endunless %}
        </a>
      </li>
    {% endunless %}
  </ul>
</figure>

{% endcapture %}{%- if workspace__share_page -%}{{ workspace__share_page | strip | strip_newlines }}{%- endif -%}{% assign workspace__share_page = nil %}
```